# Filter tuple on an nested value of a inner bag

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm quite a begginer on PigLatin and I need some (basic, I think) help.

My data is DESCRIBE as :

```
xmlToTuple: {(node_attr_id: int,tag: {(tag_attr_k: chararray,tag_attr_v: chararray)})}
```

and DUMP like this :

```
((704398904,{(lat,-13.00583333),(lon,45.24166667)}))
((1230941976,{(place,village)}))
((1230941977,{(name,Mtsahara)}))
((1751057677,{(amenity,fast_food),(name,Brochetterie)}))
((100948360,{(amenity,ferry_terminal)}))
((362795028,{(amenity,fuel),(operator,Total)}))
```

I want to extract the record which have a certain value for the tag_attr_k field. For example, give me the record where there is a tag_attr_k = amesity ? That should be :

```
((1751057677,{(amenity,fast_food),(name,Brochetterie)}))
((100948360,{(amenity,ferry_terminal)}))
((362795028,{(amenity,fuel),(operator,Total)}))
```

Anybody can explain me to do that ? I'm a bit lost…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found!

```
 XmlTag = FOREACH xmlToTuple GENERATE FLATTEN ($0);
    XmlTag2 = FOREACH XmlTag {
        tag_with_amenity = FILTER tag BY (tag_attr_k == 'amenity');
        GENERATE *, COUNT(tag_with_amenity) AS count;
    };
    XmlTag3 = FOREACH (FILTER XmlTag2 BY count > 0) GENERATE node_attr_id, node_attr_lon, node_attr_lat, tag;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a map instead of a bag of tuples.  The keys will be your `tag_attr_k`s, and your values your `tag_attr_v`s.  So one line of your data would be, e.g.,

```
(1751057677,['amenity'#'fast_food', 'name',#'Brochetterie'])
```

Then you can check to see if a key exists by attempting to access it and checking whether the value is `NULL`.

`FILTER xml BY tag_attr#'amenity' IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Thanks. great tips…but If i can not change my data set ?

Comment: You will need to write a UDF which takes a bag and makes key-value pairs out of the first two elements of each tuple in the bag.  Unfortunately, no such UDF is built-in, although you may be able to find one in a third-party jar somewhere.  It would be a pretty simple UDF to construct, however, so it would be a nice way to practice writing them if you are unfamiliar.  See this question to help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408380/apache-pig-url-parsing-into-a-map

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `map` for this, not a list of tuples. Maps are built for exactly this purpose. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#data-types

To filter out, you'll do:

```
B = FILTER A BY mymap#'amenity' IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve his problem.  This would require having maps like `[tag_attr_k#amesity, tag_attr_v#fuel]`.  So each of the attribute-value pairs would be in a separate map, and he'd still have a bag of them to look through.

Comment: you are right, let me edit it... what you are saying is what I intended to write, haha.